# Listview Content Email

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with two `TextViews` as result.One is result and other is description. My `Listview` contains 10 rows .The question is that how can I E-mail the content using android default mail composer.? When user press the email button, the contents of the Listview copy to the mail clipboard

Comment: is the email button is on your listView row as other two textViews.

Comment: No the email button is separate or outof listview like under the listview.

Comment: ok then firstly you have to click on listView on get its data according to its position .And on click of Send button pass the intent of send mail with that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String getvalue;
for(int i =0;i<getListView.getChildCount();i++){
LinearLayout layout = getListView.getChildAt(i);

getvalue = layout.getChildAt(1).getText();
```

}

```
mailbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});

          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getvalue);

          //need this to prompts email client only
          email.setType("message/rfc822");

          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"))
            }
        });
```

Comment: hey i need to send all the result not one value

Comment: Check it. i Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put On item click listner to listview that will return position of items that is your row of listview like below.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) {
               String items= yourarray.getItem(position);

               //call sendEmail method on click of that send email button.
            }
        })
```

;

```
private void sendEmail(Context context, String[] recipientList,
                String subject, String body, String title) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipientList);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            try
            {
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, title));

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Hey how can i copy or pass the contents.? I have 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

call this method onclick of email send button with email address and data as body and subject which you want to add as a field of Email composer.

```
public void sendEmail(String emaillAddressOfRecipent, String data,String strSubJect) {
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { emaillAddressOfRecipent });
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, priority.getSelectedItem() + " : "+ strSubJect);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data);
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email clients installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

where data is the dataof your listView position